# Facing some problem with GNOME Dash to Dock Extension in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dash-to-dock

Whenever my laptop is reawakened from sleep, the dock appears to be overlapped by another dock. Is someone else facing the same issue?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The below will disable the default ubuntu dock this should resolve the issue.

```
gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: Please mark as the answer if it worked for you, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Jack Rawlins' answer, you can also disable the Ubuntu Dock extension without using the terminal with the Gnome Extensions app in Ubuntu 20.04. Go to the Extensions app, and flip the "Ubuntu Dock" switch to disable it. It should do the same as the command posted by Jack.