# 'Show Applications' button getting stuck every time Ubuntu startup

Tags: gnome-shell, gui, ubuntu-gnome

I'm newbie on Ubuntu OS. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my PC, everything work fine except `Show Applications` button. When I startup Ubuntu, logged in to desktop, and click on `Show Applications` button, it was highlight (actived indicator) but nothing happen, no dim light fullscreen, just getting stuck there. When I press `Super` (Windows logo) button or click on `Activities` menu (top left of screen) now it back to work normally. It seem I need to activate once by `Super` button every time I startup Ubuntu then it will back to work normally. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the All Applications button on the **dock**? If so try this:

gnome-extensions disable ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

Here is the reference: [Facing some problem with GNOME Dash to Dock Extension in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236710/facing-some-problem-with-gnome-dash-to-dock-extension-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1327260)